# C++/CLI C# Integration

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I'm trying to understand how C# can work with C++/CLI.

I've taken an existing SDK that is used to produce plugins for my native application and have compiled it using the /CLR option.  This appears to work just fine.

Now what I would like to do is expose my unmanaged types to C#.

If I have existing structures like:

```
typedef struct _arrayi
{
    unsigned long   *data;
    int             size;
    short           width;
    short           element;
} ARRAYI;

struct api {
    ARRAYI *someval
    chart *username
}
```

How can I expose these safely to my managed types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native types are not visible to C#. If you want to expose those types to C#, write managed equivalent types. For example

```
ref class ManagedArrayI
{
    public:
    property  array<Byte> ^ Data;
    property  System::Int16 width;
    property  System::Int16 element;
}
ref class ManagedApi
{
    public:
    property System::String^ UserName;
    property ManagedArrayI^ SomeVal;
}

void ManagedCallApi(ManagedApi^ foo)
{
    marshal_context context;

    api nativeFoo;
    System::String^ userName=foo->UserName;
    nativeFoo.username=(char*)context.marshal_as<const char*>(userName);

    ARRAYI nativeBar;
    nativeFoo.someval=&nativeBar;

    //now copy properties of foo->SomeVal to nativeBar

    //call native function with nativeFoo

}
```

Comment: please, don't use `gcnew` with `marshal_context`.  Use stack semantics, so that it will be properly cleaned up in case of exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from going the C++/CLI way, there is another method called pInvoke. You export your dll functions and structs in the same way as you do for another native consumer. You just have to write Managed Stubs of these in C# in order to be able to call these. For examples, look at [www.pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net). Here you can find good examples of most of the Windows API functions and structs.

From the above mentioned site, look at the example of [WIN32_FIND_DATA](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/WIN32_FIND_DATA.html)